# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NoDefault'

Tags: plone, dexterity, paster

Running paster on Plone UnifiedInstaller 4.2.5 I get the following errors.  Any idea on the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../bin/paster", line 382, in <module>
    import paste.script.command
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2835, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 704, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2835, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2262, in activate
    map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'))
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1847, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1817, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName); module.__path__ = path
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zopeskel.basic_namespace import BasicNamespace
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/basic_namespace.py", line 2, in <module>
    from zopeskel.vars import var, DottedVar, StringVar, BooleanVar, TextVar
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/vars.py", line 2, in <module>
    from paste.script.templates import var as base_var
  File "/var/plone/my.app/buildout-cache/eggs/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/templates.py", line 145, in <module>
    NoDefault = command.NoDefault
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NoDefault'
```

My zopeskel section of base.cfg has the following entries

```
[zopeskel]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ZopeSkel <= 2.99
    zopeskel.dexterity == 1.4.1
    zopeskel.diazotheme
    Paste
    PasteDeploy
    PasteScript
    ${buildout:eggs}
```

I can run zopeskel and create a dexterity package but I can not add custom content types because of this paster issue.  My dexterity package is already installed in buildout.cfg

Comment: Sounds like you have Zopeskel, Paste version installed in your system-wide Python / Plone python interpreter and it might conflict with one used by buildout. System-wide version gets the preference - if there are (wrong) imports they get imported from the system installation first.

Comment: I had a clean install in the system.  I have resolved the issue by commenting Paste and PasteDeploy in the zopeskel section.  Paster now works.  But note that the two modules are present in the base.cfg from the unified installer templates. A bug?

Comment: Can you repeat with clean 4.3.x install?

Comment: Plone 4.3.1 has Paste and PasteDeploy in the zopeskel section of develop.cfg but it works fine.  I can create a dexterity package and add a content type.